# Rails change created_at & compare if 00.00 passed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, compare

I am changing the created_at value and compare with Time.now, which I would like to understand whether clock ticks to 00.00.

```
  <% if  (....created_at.change({ hour: 23, min: 59, sec: 59 })) >= Time.now.utc %>
```

However, when I change created_at to "23.59.59" it is not utc time zone anymore. But `Time.now.utc` is. So that my create a problem in my opinion.

Is there a better way to understand / compare, is it tomorrow or not?

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is so confused.

Can't you use `past?` method to do what you want?

http://apidock.com/rails/DateTime/past%3F